# Defining embedded XML in XMLSchema

Tags: xml, xsd

I have to validate XML file that contains embedded XML, with XML Schema. Correctness of the inner XML doesn't interest me. Which type should I use in XML Schema for this type of content? Simple `xs:string` doesn't work.

Comment: What problems are you having with using `xs:string`?

Comment: .net validator is smart and recognize that content is xml - I got error: "The element 'xxx' cannot contain child element 'yyy' because the parent element's content model is text only."

Comment: Updated my answer with a couple of alternatives which you can use with text (`xs:string`) content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of alternatives for embedding XML within another XML document.

**`xs:any:`**

You can use the `xs:any` type in your schema ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_any.asp)). However you will need to include a schema for the embedded XML (which will be used to validate it).

Alternatively, `xs:string` can be made to work if you either embed the inner XML within a `CDATA` section or escape all the `<` and `&` characters.

**`CDATA` section:**

```
<InnerXml>
  <![CDATA[
    <InnerXmlRoot>
      <InnerXmlContent>One & Two</InnerXmlContent>
    </InnerXmlRoot>
  ]]>
</InnerXml>
```

The only thing you need to be careful of with this approach is that the inner XML cannot contain `CDATA` sections as the allowed content cannot contain `]]>` (see the [XML specification](http://www.xml.com/axml/target.html#NT-CDEnd)).

**Character escaping:**

```
<InnerXml>
  &lt;InnerXmlRoot>
    &lt;InnerXmlContent>One &amp; Two&lt;/InnerXmlContent>
  &lt;/InnerXmlRoot>
</InnerXml>
```

Comment: The problem is, that inner XML can vary. I just want make validator not caring about it.

Comment: Solution with CDATA works almost fine (some formatting issues, but it's simple to solve). Thanks for help.